# Querystring in IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-identity, query-string, identityserver4

Good Morning

I have the following situation:

- The user enters the page with a querystring, for example:
  **https://app.test.com/index.html?name=jhon&age=20&city=vitoria**
- The user is not logged in, then is redirected to the user login
  screen
- Once logged in, the user is redirected to the main page of the
  "app.test" application configured on the IdentityServer which is
  https://app.test.com/index.html

My question is, how do I in IdentityServer4 so that after the user is logged in, he is redirected to the main page **with the querystring**? It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is what you'd use the `state` parameter for when doing an authorize endpoint request. If you're using the standard middleware then to be honest I'm surprised it doesn't work out of the box but it may be possible to use the OpenIdConnectEvents.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider event to manually manipulate the request.

Are you able to post details of the redirect URLs at each step in the flow?

Comment: I am using .NET Core 2.1 and find the **OnRedirectToIdentityProvider** is obsolete.
Would you have some other IdentityServer4 material that would explain more about **querystring**?

Comment: I don't see it marked as obsolete, do you have a source?

Comment: @Ruard van Elburg 
https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1310
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/909

Comment: It is not the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider that is obsolete but app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication: "The UseXyz has been replaced by ConfigureService(): AddXyz().". According to the documention you can use OnRedirectToIdentityProvider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents.onredirecttoidentityprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.1